# html5 2 image inside section with css only

Tags: html, css

Im trying to add inside a section via css 2 images to make them look like this:
[image]

but the only thing i can manage with css looking like this:

[image]

i could use divs in html  & could add the img via html
but it will be semantically wrong in HTML5 as this is a "mood" picture - and all mood pictures go into css (was told by my class teacher)
any ideas ?

```css
#Principle1 {
    background-image: url(../pictures/puzzle1.png), url('../pictures/Paranormalwikipic.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    width: 583px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
            <section id="Principle1">
                <h2>
                    מסר מספר 1: תאמין בעצמך!
                </h2>
                <p>
                    שיעור מספר אחת נמצא כמעט בכל אנימה. כל אחד צריך להאמין בעצמו, ולא לתת לדעות אחרים להשפיע עליו. מי יודע, אולי תהיה גיבור העל הבא?
                </p>
            </section>
```

Comment: try `background-position:left center, right center`

Comment: this makes the girl image behind the blue puzzle cube and no option to lift her up

Answer (score 1):

You may use this syntax on your CSS to position and zoom more than one background.

example:

```
background: 
  url(one.png) 0 0 no-repeat,
  url(two.png) -576px 100% no-repeat, 
  url(three.png) -288px 0 repeat-y;
background-size: 50px 50px, 100px 100px;
```